# EF: Where(Date.Month == m) versus Where(Date >= ... && Date <= ...)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, datepart

I have a table, `Measurements`, which has a `Date` column.
This column is indexed (is a non unique index though)

Using EntityFramework I want to get all items from a certain `month` and `year`.

**Question: What alternative is better in terms of performance?**

**Alternative 1:**

```
  var results = db.Measurements.Where(m => m.Date.Month == month && m.Date.Year == year);
```

(The resultant SQL uses the `DATEPART` function)

```
WHERE (((DATEPART (month, [Extent1].[Date])) = @p__linq__1) OR ((DATEPART (month, [Extent1].[Date]) IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))) AND (((DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[Date])) = @p__linq__2) OR ((DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[Date]) IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL)))
```

(...though I'm not sure why there is a "OR null" case)

**Alternative 2:**

```
  DateTime firstDateOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
  DateTime lastDateOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));

  var results = db.Measurements.Where(m => m.Date >= firstDateOfMonth && m.Date <= lastDateOfMonth);
```

(The resultant SQL uses operators `>=` and `<=`)

```
  WHERE ([Extent1].[Date] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= @p__linq__2)
```

Comment: This may depend on whether the YEAR and MONTH functions are sargable (which means their involvement still allows the use of an index) but I have no idea if they are. Still, it might give you something to search for. Hopefully someone else knows something more definite.

Comment: Sargable? thats something new for me... can I specify the column to be sargable within the `OnModelCreating` of my `DbContext`?

Comment: No, whether a function is sargable or not is a property of the function being used, not something you can opt into or force.

Comment: The `DATEPART` function (SQL Server) is sargable?

Comment: Using functions including datepart in the field will prevent SQL Server from using indexes to search with it

Comment: @JamesZ so that is telling me I should opt for the alternative 2

Comment: Yes, definitely use the one with dates directly in the criteria

Comment: Just wanted to add that the reason for the "or null" case is that the LINQ expression is in .NET and therefore `null == null` should return `true`. But `NULL = NULL` is `false` in SQL and therefore EF has to add a special case to check for it.

Comment: @ChrisV but why is that case considered?  in my code the month and year variables are nullable, they are `int?`, but I pass `month.Value` and `year.Value` to the query... so in the query it should never be null